# Is there Linux support for TRIM on SSD drives?

Tags: linux, ssd, trim

Does any know if there is a way to enable TRIM support on Linux for SSDs?  This is included with Windows 7, and I was surprised that I couldn't find much information about it under Linux.

Info on SSD and TRIM can be found here - http://www.anandtech.com/storage/showdoc.aspx?i=3531&p=10

Comment: Linus himself is a big fan of SSD drives, so I'd suspect them to be well supported. http://torvalds-family.blogspot.com/2008/10/so-i-got-one-of-new-intel-ssds.html

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Notice that you probably need a more recent kernel than 2.6.28, see [here](http://lwn.net/Articles/331490/) (based on 2.6.30-rc4 with last activity in May this year). I do not know to what degree that tree has been merged, maybe you can search the `linux-ide@vger.kernel.org` mailing list. Update: see for instance [this](http://lkml.org/lkml/2009/8/13/266) thread (also discussed on the kernel list).

For using TRIM you are probably interested in [hdparm-9.20](http://sourceforge.net/projects/hdparm/), released a few days ago (and I see there is even a newer wiper-1.7 release).

Update: See also this [LWN article](http://lwn.net/Articles/353411/) about the relationship between filesystem, TRIM, performance and SSD disks.

Answer (score 5):

Linux supported the TRIM command in 2.6.28, released on December 25, 2008.  See [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-kernel-advances/index.html) for details.

Comment: Does this require file system support also?

Comment: [citation needed]

Answer (score 2):

I think Linux already supports Trim.  Its just no SSD has support for it yet.  The firmware upgrade is required for current generation OCZ and Intel drives for Trim to be enabled.

Comment: According to http://www.ocztechnology.com/products/flash_drives/ocz_vertex_series_sata_ii_2_5-ssd at least some OCZ products support TRIM.

Comment: Then you are mistaken.  I am following OCZ news in their forums and TRIM has not been released yet.

Comment: Really?  That's strange, because that page explicitly includes the following quote: "With the latest firmware update you also get a TRIM tool which other SSD manufacturers have failed to implement so far."  Strange that they would falsely claim a feature they don't have, but it wouldn't be the first time a company did so.

Comment: That's a review site that got it wrong.  I think what they meant to say is the latest FW has idle garbage collection.

Answer (score 2):

For ext4 you have to add the [discard](http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/ext4.txt) option in your fstab to enable ATA Trim.

See also this nice [how-to](https://sites.google.com/site/lightrush/random-1/howtoconfigureext4toenabletrimforssdsonubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

Initial support added in 2.6.28, 2.6.33 has "full" trim support... whatever that means.

Answer (score 0):

I tracked TRIM command on UBUNTU 9.10. But I can't find any TRIM Command when I'm using the kernel 2.6.31.
When I generated TRIM command using the hdparm, I can find TRIM command.
So, I think current linux kernel version does not support TRIM command.