# How to maintain a SSD drive on Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssd, ubuntu-10.04, trim

I am running Ubuntu 10.04 on a Intel X25-M PostVille 160 Go SSD drive with ext4. How can I tell if there's something wrong ? What should/can I do to maintain its performance/health ? Should I use TRIM, is Linux recent support for TRIM reliable ?

This may look as a duplicate of [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/19202/linux-support-for-trim-on-ssd-drives), but I am more asking in term of good practices and learning how to use this new technology the right way...

Comment: Also see: http://superuser.com/questions/125069/how-do-i-verify-that-trim-is-activated-linux. And TRIM (if enabled) should run automatically in the background - the user shouldn't have to do anything specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can us [SMART to monitor the SSD](https://serverfault.com/questions/10326/does-ssd-support-s-m-a-r-t) as you'd monitor a normal HDD. Beside that, I don't think that there is anything 'special' you should think about...except regular backups.

Comment: The one who has given a -1 could have explained why...

Comment: @Julien Nocoulaud: Yepp, I'd like to know why, too.